# Intent for call does not open dialer

Tags: android, api, android-intent, sdk, android-3.0-honeycomb

I am using Intent to make calls from my app.

Here is the onClick for the TextView on which if the user clicks I want to open the dialer:

```
txtCall1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
```

> ```
>                   public void onClick(View arg0) {
>                       Intent callIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_DIAL);
>                       callIntent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_DEFAULT);
>                       callIntent.setData(Uri.parse("tel:"+ci.getContactPhone1()));
>                       startActivity(callIntent);  
>                   }
>               });
> ```

My problem is that with Api level 12 devices instead of dialer a dialog opens which asks to add the number to contact. This is not the case for Api level 19 or 18.

This is tools I am using. I have just updated my everything. 
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> My problem is that with Api level 12 devices instead of dialer a dialog opens which asks to add the number to contact

That is because API Level 12 devices (Android 3.1) all were tablets without dialers.

> What am I supposed to do?

Ignore API Level 12, as approximately zero devices use it.

Beyond that, if your app **must** run on a phone, add `<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.telephony"/>` to your manifest, to indicate that your app requires telephony capability, so you are not distributed to tablets without dialers.